# Rings that appear as quotients $B/I$ of subrings$B \subseteq F$ of fields $F$ and for $I \subseteq B$ ideals

Tags: ring-theory, quotient-spaces, integral-domain

What are the rings $A$ that appear as quotients $B/I$ of subrings$B \subseteq F$ of fields $F$ and for $I \subseteq B$ ideals? For each $A$, give an explicit formula for a ring $B$ and a field $F$.

For any ring homomorphism $\varphi: B \to F$ for some ring $B$ and field $F$, we know that $B/\ker \varphi \cong \textrm{Im }F$. If $A$ is a domain then we may let $I = \{ 0\}$, $B = A$, and $F$ be the field of fractions of $A$.

I am wondering if you could tell me (1) if my reasoning so far is correct, and (2) how to proceed from here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In case $A$ is an integral domain, what you did works.

In general, any commutative ring is a quotient of an integral domain. For example, for each $a\in A$ define a variable $x_a$, and let $B$ be the very large polynomial ring $B=\mathbb{Z}[\{x_a\}_{a\in A}]$. There is a clear surjective homomorphism $B\to A$, and so $A$ is a quotient of $B$. Now take $F$ to be the field of fractions of $B$.

Comment: thank you, I am wondering if you could explain your motivation for coming up with the $B$. Also, why can you not just take $B = A$?

Comment: @loveandlight Taking $B=A$ will not give us anything, because we don't know that $A$ is an integral domain. We want to present $A$ as a quotient of an integral domain, which is equivalent to find an integral domain $B$ and a surjective homomorphism $B\to A$. The ring $B$ that I defined is the most simple choice, there exists a very natural surjective homomorphism in this case.